# Raspberry Pi Camera Module with Picamera

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi3

Hi I am trying to make drive recorder by raspberry pi3 and camera module.
Then I am using picamera which is python library that uses the official camera module for development.

Here is a [document of picamera](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/index.html).

Basic idea is this.
Record for 10 min and loop this.
If user pushed button that connected to GPIO pin, stop recording.

I thought I can use the callback function to end the recording.
But I couldn't stop camera recording by callback method.
Does anyone tell me my recognition of callback is wrong?

Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera
import os
import sys
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

class driveRecoder():
    try:
        #Button setup
        SWITCH_PIN=21
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(SWITCH_PIN,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

        #Camera setup
        camera = PiCamera()
        resolution_width = 1920
        resolution_height = 1080
        record_time=60
        camera.resolution = (resolution_width, resolution_height)
        camera.framerate = 30
        camera.led = False

        def shutdown():
            print "shutdown"
            os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

        #Callback function
        def stopRecording():
            camera.stop_recording()
            print("録画終了")
            #I want to power down after stop recording 
            #GPIO.cleanup()
            #shutdown()

        GPIO.add_event_detect(SWITCH_PIN,GPIO.FALLING)
        GPIO.add_event_callback(SWITCH_PIN,stopRecording)

        while True:
            try:
                print("録画開始")

                #setup file name and directory path to save
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                dir_name = now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                dir_path = '/home/admini/Video/'+dir_name
                file_name = now.strftime('%H%M%S')

                #Make each date folder if not exist folder
                if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
                        os.makedirs(dir_path)
                        os.chmod(dir_path, 0777)

                #Recording 10 min the loop
                camera.start_recording(dir_path+'/'+file_name+'.h264')
                camera.wait_recording(record_time)
                camera.stop_recording()
                print("録画終了")
                    sleep(2)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                camera.stop_recording()
                break
            finally:
                pass
        print("録画終了")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ctl+c終了")
        GPIO.cleanup()
        sys.exit(0)
    finally:
        pass
    print("終了")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull this function out of the class for DriveRecorder.  I am surprised you aren't seeing an error.  I would pull "shutdown" function out, too.

```
#Callback function
def stopRecording():
    camera.stop_recording()
    print("録画終了")
    #I want to power down after stop recording 
    #GPIO.cleanup()
    #shutdown()
```

Comment: Now I delete class then I run program, I got KeyError(1924434000) in module 'threading'. I never see this word keyerror in ~ do you know this?